# Bootstrap dropdown isn't opening

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm guessing this is an easy problem for most guys. I copied the standard template from the bootstrap website, but the dropdown menu in the navbar isn'topening when I click it. Can someone see why?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <a
    class="navbar-brand"
    routerLinkActive="active current"
    routerLink="/">
    Home
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a
          class="nav-link"
          routerLinkActive="active current"
          routerLink="/shopping-cart">
          Shopping Cart
          <span
            class="caret">
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">User</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My orders</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Manage Orders</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Manage Products</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Out</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the developer console?

Comment: I get none. I just click it and it does nothing.

Comment: Before you copy and pasted the example, did you read the [Getting Started](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) section and copy and pasted the stylesheets along with the necessary script references?  It does say in the **JS** section, *Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.*

Comment: Have you added bootstrapjs and jquery scripts in your html?

Comment: You are using bootstrap that is depending on boostrap.js for toggling .open class. You must create directive that does that foe you.

Comment: I am learning Angular. I added bootstrap in my app.module file. Everything else of bootstrap seems to work fine. It's just the dropdown tht isn't working as I'd hoped.

Comment: Can you show me how you are import files? Because bootstrap is a framework that is css + js you think everything is working but thats css only.

Comment: Maybe this will help, and you don't need angular to do that for you: https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/RxguB/

Comment: For adding css and js you go to .angular-cli.json and in styles array and scripts array import what you need. There is also ng-bootstrap specific components for angular.

Comment: As mentioned by @stojevskimilan, and as I can testify from my own experience, [ng-bootstrap components](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) work well, including [the dropdown](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples).

Comment: Yes, I solved it using the ng-bootstrap component dropdown. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is most likely caused by the absence of necessary scripts tags.  On [Bootstrap's website](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) it says under the **JS** section:

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.

Furthermore, there is a starter template that you can use with the navbar component that you are trying to use.

[image]

This provides all necessary references to work with bootstrap correctly.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I am using this in Angular(forgot to mention this). Is it still necessary to add the scripts after already added bootstrap in app.module file?

Answer (score 0):

As GTown-Coder mentioned, you need to include the jquery scripts and sure bootstrap...

There are two ways. I prefer the following for simplicity

In the index.html at  *(header should work too, if not include the scripts into the body at last)* you must add the 4 lines from Bootstrap ([LINK](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/) [Its download page of bootstrap 4])

Then your Dropdown should work.

Other way is to install (via npm, [LINK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap)) bootstrap, jquery, tether, popperjs and add the script paths to .angular-cli.json -> this can be tricky if there are some missing dependcies.

Are there still problems, let us know!